# c struct pointer array allocate sigsegv

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm new to c and I have the following problem:

after executing this part of the code

```
TypeDefStruct tdss[10];
for(...) {
        TypeDefStruct *tds = (TypeDefStruct*)malloc(sizeof(TypeDefStruct));
        strcpy(&tds->data, charPointerArray[index]) // works (not original code)
        memcpy((void*) &tdss[index], (void*) &tds, sizeof(TypeDefStruct)); // new
        free(tds);  // new
    }
```

an error occurs here

```
TypeDefStruct *tds = &tdss[0]; // worked before
printf("\twith input: \"%s\"\n", tds->data); // worked before
```

the TypeDefStruct:

```
typedef struct TypeDefStruct{
    char* data;
} TypeDefStruct;
```

also the error sigsagv occurs at some point (don't know where, may not here at all...)

what I'm trying to do

I am trying to copy this struct into an array and manage my memory correctly.

please, don't mind asking for more information!

Comment: The problem with [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (which you have) is that sometimes it might *seem* to work.

Comment: I have two pieces of advice for you: 1) [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org) is the best available tool for diagnosing what has *actually* gone wrong in cases of memory corruption. It is very common for the true cause of such bugs to be nowhere near the point where the program crashes. 2) For us to help you, we need a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- a complete program, that we can run for ourselves and watch crash, containing no more code than is strictly necessary to reproduce the problem. You may discover the bug yourself while writing this.

Comment: And a third, unrelated piece of advice: `TypeDefStruct` is a *terrible* name for a data type.  Think of something more meaningful.

Comment: thanks for your advices!
the names are changed like some people do with foo, bar. And the program is huge. this will take a while.

Comment: I think i got a part of my problem figured out. `memcpy((void*) &tdss[index], (void*) &tds, sizeof(TypeDefStruct)); // new` has a syntax error! Since tds is a type defined struct we don't need the `&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this did not solve all my errors. Also not the sigsegv.

But there is a Syntax error in

`memcpy((void*) &tdss[index], (void*) &tds, sizeof(TypeDefStruct));` !

Since `tds` is a type defined struct we don't need the `&`. At least I think so...

Answer (score 2):

```
strcpy(&tds->data, charPointerArray[index]) // works (not original code)
```

`data` is an uninitialized object, you need to allocate an array with `malloc`.
Also `&tds->data` argument is wrong, you need to use `tds->data`.

Comment: @SteveMcGregor people will only comment on the code your posted; moreover the `&` error is serious.